# store remote data in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I've created a autocomplete searchfield in which users can type a movie title and it will show all the results like this > https://i.stack.imgur.com/xifLk.png

The next thing I want to do is give the user a option to save a movie title to the database. As you can see in the image every result has a "add" button. This is a link with the ID of the movie in it's target. It can be anything like a button or a span etc.

When a user clicks on the add button I want to store the movie title of the movie with that ID in my database.

I've generated a model called movie and a collumn called title. I've also generated a controller called movie and I've created a form field which lets the user type the movie title and then save it to do movie model > title collumn. But this was more for testing. Like I said above I want to save the movie title from a specific ID into my database.

I know how to get the JSON respons from TMDB api, 
[click](https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/62?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4)

But what I don't know is how to link my "add" button to that response and then grab some data like title or poster url and post it in my database.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass the id into the movie controller's new method, then you can populate the form with the data you get back from remote

```
class MovieController
  def new
    @movie = Movie.new
    @movie_data = remove_server.fetch(params[:movie_id])

    @movie.title = @movie_data.title
    # other attributes

  end
end
```

Comment: Could you give me a example of how the view should look? Would it just be a form_for with a submit button? Also I think you made a typo with the `remove_server` should it be `remote_server` or a url to the api part?